# Call directive method from transcluded content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access a method in a directive from translcuded content. My HTML looks like:

```
<typeahead class="typeahead" model="customers" filtered-model="customersfiltered" ng-model="selectedcustomer">
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="select(customer)" ng-repeat="customer in customersfiltered | filter:filter | limitTo:10">
      {{customer.firstname}} {{customer.lastname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</typeahead>
```

And my AngularJS directive:

```
directive('typeahead', function ($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        model: '=',
        filteredModel: '='
      },
      template: '<div class="typeahead"><form><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="col-lg-12" ng-model="filter"></form><div ng-transclude></div></div>', //
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.filterArray = function(filterString){
          $scope.filteredModel=  $filter('filter')($scope.model, filterString);
        }

        $scope.clear = function(){
          $scope.filteredModel = [];
        }

        $scope.$watch('filter', function(){
          if($scope.filter) {
            $scope.filterArray($scope.filter);
          } else {
            $scope.clear();
          }
        });
      },
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        $scope.select = function(customer){
          console.log("dwadad");
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

The problem here is that I cannot access the select() function inside the link function() from the ng-click event of the transcluded content (list-element).

**Have somebody an idea how to solve this?**

Here is a Plunker of the current code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSCJDt91OyJGqYBDCgHe)

Comment: Can you create a plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that. From the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> (...) The advantage of transclusion is that the linking function receives a
>   transclusion function which is pre-bound to the correct scope. In a
>   typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the
>   transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope. This
>   makes it possible for the widget to have private state, and the
>   transclusion to be bound to the parent (pre-isolate) scope.

In other words, the scope of the transcluded DOM is a sibling, not a child, of the directive's scope. So you can't access it from there, and I think that's correct. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to bind the transcluded content to the right scope.

Comment: So what is the best practise for that problem? How can i Call the select method?

Comment: I guess you should rethink what you're doing. Do you really need to use transclusion?

Comment: The idea was to create an autocomplete directive, but for different data items. In this example i need a customer directive, obviously to search for customers. So i need firstname and lastname in the result-item. Maybe later i need a some other presentation of the result items (e.g. manufacturer and model). So i thought this would be the best solution for "dynamic" templates.

Comment: What's the `select` method supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$$nextSibling`:

```
link: function($scope) {

    $scope.$$nextSibling.select = function(customer) {
        alert('used isolated scope using $$nextSibling');
    }

},
```